# Access 2007 - all code not running (possible reference issue)

Tags: ms-access, reference, vba

I had a Microsoft Office 2010 free trial and then converted to a full paid version of Office 2007. When I try to run any code in Access, I get the following error message: "The expression [NAME_OF_SUB_HERE] you entered as the Event Property Setting produced the following error: expected text or binary". This appears regardless of how simple the function is.

From some searching, it seems that it may be a references issue, where Access is referencing some libraries from the other version. However, it looks like 2010 was uninstalled during the 2007 installation (which was done by someone else). There is a similar question here on SO (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75246/what-are-the-implications-of-running-a-microsoft-access-database-in-both-2003-an) as well as some information elsewhere about editing the registry to correct the references issue. However, these are all for running two versions simultaneously. All I want is to run one version (2007). How can I find and remove whatever residue is (I assume) left from the 2010 trial version, or correctly resolve the references, so I can run my code? Or, if this is not actually the reason, what can I do to get my code to run?

Thanks a lot,
   bsg

Answer (score 1):

The following KB article contains a list of steps on how to manually remove all traces (files, registry entries, etc.) of Office 2010 from a system:

- [How to uninstall or remove Microsoft Office 2010 suites](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290301) (Method 4)

To make sure this doesn't break your Office 2007 installation, I'd

- remove Office 2007
- manually remove all remainders of Office 2010
- reinstall Office 2007
- install Office 2007 Service Packs

I cannot guarantee that this will fix the problem you are having, but if you suspect remainders of Office 2010 to be the culprit, I'd give this a try.

Comment: It might be worth trying a repair first, but the full remove / restore sounds a better bet in the long run. Repairs worked for me when I was messing about with multiple versions, but I was using an old machine intended for that purpose.

Comment: Would I be able to do this safely without removing Office 2007? It was installed on my machine my the IT help department and I'd rather not have to go through that long process again.

Comment: I suppose you could also manually check your references for anything like Office 14.0 (12.0 is for 2007), remove that and add manually a reference for that shown file for your 'old' (12.0) version. Those files are located in the common files folder, you should be able to google the exact place. Worked for me, I got in trouble after installing Visio 2010 test version. Might be worth a try, if the references are wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions; unfortunately, none of them have worked. :( There doesn't seem to be any remnant of Office 2010 on my computer, but I still can't run code in Access 2007. Any ideas on what the problem can be, and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

try uninstall office 2007 clear your pc with 
[CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download)
and reinstall office again.